# get pointer on byte array from unmanaged c++ dll in c#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling, unmanaged

in c++ I have such function

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) uint8* bufferOperations(uint8* incoming, int size)
```

I am trying to call it from c# like this

```
[DllImport("MagicLib.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
//[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]//, ArraySubType=UnmanagedType.SysUInt)]
public static extern byte[] bufferOperations(byte[] incoming, int size);
```

But I get the
Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination

((( The question is - how to marshal this correctly?
Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

byte[] is a .Net array type with known length. You can't marshal byte* to it, because .Net does not know the length of output array. You should try manual marshalling. Replace byte[] with byte*. Then, do like this:

```
[DllImport("MagicLib.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte* bufferOperations(byte* incoming, int size);

public void TestMethod()
{
    var incoming = new byte[100];
    fixed (byte* inBuf = incoming)
    {
        byte* outBuf = bufferOperations(inBuf, incoming.Length);
        // Assume, that the same buffer is returned, only with data changed.
        // Or by any other means, get the real lenght of output buffer (e.g. from library docs, etc).
        for (int i = 0; i < incoming.Length; i++)
            incoming[i] = outBuf[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: SPasibo Vladimir! BbI MHE Ochenb pomogli =)  Otkuda BbI ?

Comment: @curiousity. No problem, I'm from Moscow, Luxoft. I think it is more polite to other users to write in English. :)

Comment: This is one of the few examples that actually works. And it's the simplest.

Comment: That really works :)..needed to append unsafe keyword to the function

Comment: This worked really nicely. Was looking to interop with an old DLL and this solution helped me to achieve that, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `unsafe contexts` in this case. Just use [IntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.aspx).

```
[DllImport("MagicLib.DLL", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr bufferOperations(IntPtr incoming, int size);
```

And then you can use [Marshal.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy.aspx) to get your byte-array from it.