# Calling C++ dll from C#. "Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination."

Tags: c#, pinvoke

My Header file.

```
extern "C"  class MyFuncs
{
 public:
    __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char PassImage(unsigned char buffer, int size);
};
```

CPP file.

```
unsigned char MyFuncs::PassImage(unsigned char buffer, int size)
{
    return buffer;
}
```

All works well except when i am returning buffer back to my main application.

```
    [DllImport("ExampleDLL.dll", EntryPoint = "?PassImage@MyFuncs@Funcs@@QAEXEH@Z")]
    public static extern byte[] PassImage(byte[] a, int count);
```

The error occurs when i am return unsigned char to byte[].

If i change byte[] to byte i get a value back an no error.

This is the exact error:

> Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type
>   combination.

How can I accept back unsigned char to byte[]?

Comment: Something must be off in the code example you posted.  an unsigned char is not an array.  Maybe that should be unsigned char * ?

Comment: Beyond the erroneous use of `unsigned char`, you can't return a `byte[]` like that.

Comment: I just changed it to unsinged char * and still same error.

Comment: And I repeat, you cannot return a `byte[]` like that. What we need to understand is what you are trying to do. You also need to get on top of what `unsigned char` is. It is a single scalar. It's not an array. Oh, and you also have an instance method which is not good too. So, it's just a total mess at the moment. You need to step back, go more slowly, think more deeply. Thrashing around won't get you anyway. Seek understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `unsigned char` should be an `unsigned char *` :)

EDIT:
You also need to pass the length of the array and handle it as a byte pointer in C# because .NET doesn't know the length of it. Described in this article: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268625/get-pointer-on-byte-array-from-unman‌​aged-c-dll-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268625/get-pointer-on-byte-array-from-unman%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Baged-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char * PassImage(unsigned char *buffer, int size); still same error.

Comment: Ok, then you need to pass also the length of the array and handle it as a byte pointer in C# because .NET doesn't know the length of the byte array (it's actually a pointer, but you want to use it as an array) passed. Described in this article: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268625/get-pointer-on-byte-array-from-unmanaged-c-dll-in-c-sharp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268625/get-pointer-on-byte-array-from-unmanaged-c-dll-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You've accepted this answer, but it is completely wrong. You cannot return `byte[]` on the C# side. Your unmanaged function is an instance method with `thiscall` calling convention.  [Demangle](http://demangler.com/) it to this: `public: void __thiscall Funcs::MyFuncs::PassImage(unsigned char,int)` If you want help, let me know!!

Comment: Hi david, i changed it to unsigned char *. Except when i return the unsigned char * back to C#, it had no idea of the length.

Comment: You accepted this answer. I've no idea why. It gets one issue right but misses so many more. If you want to progress you need to back up and try to understand. I don't see much sign of that. I can't help until you do that.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ you return an `unsigned char`, which is one byte long. In C# you expect a byte *array*. You probably want to return an `unsigned char *` from C++.

Comment: __declspec(dllexport) unsigned char * PassImage(unsigned char *buffer, int size); Still not working. Same error