# How to use pythonnet to make C# function return bytearray parameter?

Tags: c#, python, arrays, dllimport, python.net

I am trying to return a bytearray from a function from a imported C# DLL.  I do not know how to.

I have imported a C# Assembly into Python using pythonnet. I have to use C# because the C# dll is a third party dll for a piece of hardware I'm using. I cannot edit that dll.

From this function, I have successfully returned reference types that are not bytearray.

```
import clr
clr.AddReference(R'C:...\RFID Chip Sorter Project\UHFReader18CSharp.dll')
from ReaderB import StaticClassReaderB 

fComAdr = 255
EPC = bytearray(13)
Totallen = int = 0
CardNum = int = 0

z = StaticClassReaderB.Inventory_G2(fComAdr, 0, 0, 0, EPC, Totallen, CardNum, 3)
print("z=", z)
print ("Z[0]=", z[0])
print("EPC=", EPC)
```

This is the function inside the dll when I use dotpeek:

```
[DllImport("Basic.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int Inventory_G2(
  ref byte ConAddr,
  byte AdrTID,
  byte LenTID,
  byte TIDFlag,
  byte[] EPClenandEPC,
  ref int Totallen,
  ref int CardNum,
  int PortHandle);
```

This is the function description:

```
Function int StaticClassReaderB.Inventory_G2 (unsigned char *ComAdr, unsigned char AdrTID, unsigned char LenTID, unsigned char TIDFlag, unsigned char *EPClenandEPC, int * Totallen, int *CardNum, int FrmHandle);

Parameter: 

ComAdr: Input, pointed to the address of the reader.

AdrTID:Input,query TID’s start address.

LenTID: Input,query TID’s data word number.

TIDFlag: Input,query TID’s flag. 

TIDFlag=1:query TID.

TIDFlag=0:query EPC. 

EPClenandEPC: Output, Pointed to the array storing the inventory result. It is the EPC data of tag Reader read. The unit of the array includes 1 byte EPCLen and N (the value of EPCLen) bytes EPC. It is the former high-word, low word in the EPC of each tag. It is the former high-byte, low byte in the each word.

Totallen: Output. Pointed to the byte count of the  EPClenandEPC.

CardNum: Output. Pointed to the number of tag detected.

FrmHandle: Handle of the corresponding communication port the reader is connected. The handle value is got when calling function AutoOpenComPort or OpenComPort. 

Returns: 

Zero value when successfully, value:

0x01  Return before Inventory finished

0x02  the Inventory-scan-time overflow

0x03  More Data

0x04  Reader module MCU is Full

others when error occurred.
```

Actual results:

z = (1, 0, 13, 1)

z[0]= 1

EPC= bytearray(b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')

The first returned value should be the "Return value" of the function. Which is okay.

0, 13, 1 are ref values ComAdr, Totallen, and CardNum, respectively. However, what is clearly missing is "EPClenandEPC". EPClenandEPC is a bytearray. It doesn't have the "ref" and it is not returning for some reason.

When I typed print(EPC) I expected it to print the obtained bytearray, but clearly I am doing it wrong.

I also briefly tried using reflection but I am not familiar with it.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe of use? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8268625/get-pointer-on-byte-array-from-unmanaged-c-dll-in-c-sharp